# service to service communication i.e. IIS wcf service and wcf hosted in Windows service

Tags: windows, wcf

I am Implementing the  service to service communication i.e. IIS wcf service and wcf hosted in Windows service

1. one WCF service hosted in Windows service
2. consume above service in windows application i.e. Exe which will have one access db behind it e.g. AccessDB1
3. then one wcf service hosted in IIS which will have its own access db e.g.
   AccessDB2
4. so at the end there are 2 Accessdbs, from exe on some button click transfer some data from DB2 to DB.
5. then do the vice versa thing that transfer data from AccessDB1 to AccessDB2.

### How to do that in this way . i have tried this code

- Created Iservice1 Interface and declare two methods 
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IService1
  {

  ```
  [OperationContract]
  string InsertUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo);

  [OperationContract]
  DataSet SelectUserDetails();
  ```

  }
- Implements this Methods in Service1.svc Class

  public class Service1 : IService1
  { 
     // string connetionString = null;
      OleDbConnection cnn;
      string connetionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Anand\Database\UserDB.accdb";

  ```
  public DataSet SelectUserDetails()
  {

      OleDbConnection cnn;

      cnn = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
      cnn.Open();
      OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select UserID,UserName,Country,Email from 
      UserRecord order by UserId ", cnn);
      OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      da.Fill(ds);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      cnn.Close();
      return ds;
  }




  public string InsertUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo)
  {

      string Message;

      OleDbConnection cnn;         
      cnn = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
      cnn.Open();

      string str = "insert into UserRecord values('"+userInfo.UserID+"','" + 
      userInfo.UserName + "','" + userInfo.Password + "','" + userInfo.Country + 
      "','" + userInfo.Email + "') ";
      OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, cnn);

      try
      {
          int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

          if (result == 1)
          {
              Message = userInfo.UserName + " Details inserted successfully";
          }
          else
          {
              Message = userInfo.UserName + " Details not inserted successfully";
          }
          cnn.Close();
          return Message;
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {

          throw;
      }

  }
  ```
- After that create Windows Service and given Service Reference into Windows Service and Create the Service Reference Object

  ```
  public partial class UserRegistration : Form
  ```

  {
      ServiceReference1.Service1Client service = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();

  ```
  public UserRegistration()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      showdata(); 
  }

  private void showdata()  // to show the data in the DataGridView
  {
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      ds = service.SelectUserDetails();   
      dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
      dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      ServiceReference1.UserDetails objuserdetail = new ServiceReference1.UserDetails(); // add type reference
      objuserdetail.UserID = Int32.Parse(txtuserId.Text);
      objuserdetail.UserName = txtUserName.Text;
      objuserdetail.Password = txtPass.Text;
      objuserdetail.Country = txtCountry.Text;
      objuserdetail.Email = txtEmailId.Text;
      service.InsertUserDetails(objuserdetail);
      showdata();
      Empty();
  }

  public void Empty()
  {
      txtCountry.Text = "";
      txtEmailId.Text = "";
      txtPass.Text = "";
      txtuserId.Text = "";
      txtUserName.Text = "";

  }
  ```

  }

Comment: have you tried anything yet? You should provide some coding attempts so that the answers can focus on that.

Comment: Check this Above code i have created already this is suitable for solution ?